# HTML5 PushState lightbox

Tags: html, backbone.js, pushstate

On Behance.net I’ve seen a very smart way of using lightboxes, where an entire page open in a lightbox (like a video or a presentation), but also makes the URL change. If a user shares this URL, the new visitor will see the content, but now in another page (as the new visitor can’t view it in a lightbox, as we wouldn’t know which page would lay behind). Andof cause if the user closes the lightbox the URL will go back to the former page.

You can see it yourself here: https://www.behance.net

We’re building a project using BackboneJS and also uses HTML5 Pushstate, but we haven’t figured out yet, how to do this.

Does anyone of you know?

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)

```
var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
history.pushState(stateObj, "page 2", "bar.html");
```

`stateObj` is any data you want to pass to the `popState` event.